# CodeLite how build app?

Tags: c++, mingw, codelite

I've installed CodeLite with minGW and wxWidget (I think so). I've written program in C++, simple, small. The problem is, that when I click on Build menu, all options are grayed.

I checked build settings and I think that they are ok, but I'm not sure.

How build my program in CodeLite?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an open workspace? codelite requires a workspace..

Try this:
from codelite's main menu: Workspace -> new project
In the dialog that shows up (on the left) select: "Console -> Simple executable (g++)"
Fill the project name and path an click OK.

Now try and build (F7) - codelite should invoke g++.
You can now simple replace the default main.cpp content with your code and continue from there

HTH,
Eran